# Definition of extreme point which involve two norm $1$ points

Tags: reference-request, functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $E$ be a Banach space. 
Denote $B_E$ and $S_E$ to be the unit ball and sphere of $E$ respectively.

A common definition of extreme point of $B_E$ that I have came across is the following:

> **Definition $1$**  $x$ is an extreme point of $B_E$ if $$x = \frac{1}{2}(y+z)$$ for some $y,z\in B_E,$ then $x=y=z.$

I have seen another definition of extreme point which involves $y$ and $z$ to be norm $1.$ For example, [Lei Li et al. paper, page $549,$ paragraph starts with 'On the other hand,...'](http://or.nsfc.gov.cn/bitstream/00001903-5/171393/1/1000013721525.pdf) and [Botelho's et al. paper, page $823,$ first sentence of the proof of Theorem $3$](https://ac.els-cdn.com/S0022247X11003131/1-s2.0-S0022247X11003131-main.pdf?_tid=348cde9e-f6b9-11e7-b82f-00000aacb35f&acdnat=1515666285_21885e335fb91ef5d2a1274eacf293ab).

They use the following definition of extreme point:

> **Definition $2$** $x$ is an extreme point of $B_E$ if 
>   $$x = \frac{1}{2} (y+z)$$ for some $y,z\in S_E,$ then $x=y=z.$

I can prove that Definition $1$ implies Definition $2.$
But I am not able to prove its converse. 
So here is my question:

> **Question:** Does Definition $2$ imply Definition $1?$ If yes, can prove a proof or reference? Otherwise, can provide counterexample?

Comment: The definitions are equivalent, but this question is not at the appropriate the level for MO. I voted to close for migration to MSE. The question should be well-received there.

Comment: The implication 2$\Rightarrow$1 follows e.g. from the Borsuk-Ulam theorem (also known as Ham Sandwich problem). Note that you can restrict yourself to two dimensions.

Comment: @Jan-ChristophSchlage-Puchta: Can you elaborate more? I do not see why Borsuk-Ulam theorem provides the implication of $2\Rightarrow 1.$

Comment: You have to show that every interior point is the midpoint of a secant. By intersecting everything with a plane we may assume that the Banach space is $\mathbb{R}^2$. Let $x$ be an interior point, For each point $p$ on the boundary define $f(p)=|p-x|-|q-x|$, where $q$ is the other intersection of the "circle" with the line through $p$ and $x$. Then $f$ is continuous and $f(p)=-f(q)$, hence on the arc from $p$ to $q$ there is a zero of $f$, which gives the secant. A little care has to be taken in the cae that $q$ is not unique, i.e. $x$ is on the boundary and the boundary contains segments.

Comment: Much simpler: If x is an interior point of the unit ball, there must be some $\epsilon>0$ such that $B_\epsilon(x)\subseteq B_E$. Let $y\neq 0$ Then $x+\epsilon/2 y/\|y\|$ and $x-\epsilon/2 y/\|y\|$ are also interior points and $x$ lies in the middle between them.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker: You have shown that any interior point is a midpoint of two interior points. But what will this achieve?

Comment: @Idonknow It's not enough. If you can show that a point is never an extreme point according to Definition 1 unless $y$ and $z$ are in the sphere, you are done. But this is not the right place for discussing this.